# Agrupar por mês ou semana com Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho um projeto o qual tem gerencia dos meus investimentos, isso é, ele pega o meu extrato diário e salva no meu projeto para que eu consiga ver o quanto está rendendo, em resumo eu tenho uma tabela que são diariamente esses valores, eu já consigo gerar as informações separadas por dia e funciona perfeitamente (na realidade é um pouco mais complexo que isso o que faço mas a base é essa);

Porem agora está ficando ruim visualizar quando pego um range de data muito grande por exemplo 1 ano, ele lista todos os dias, eu queria uma forma de poder agrupar por mês ou semana,

Desde já agradeço todas e qualquer ajuda.

```
        $rows =  AtivosExtrato::select('titulo_id', DB::raw('SUM(valor_bruto_atual) AS valor'), 'data_imports.data_import as created_at')
        ->join('titulos','titulo_id', '=', 'titulos.id' )
        ->join('representantes','representante_id', '=', 'representantes.id' )
        ->join('data_imports','data_import_id', '=', 'data_imports.id' )
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id) 
        ->whereBetween('data_imports.data_import', [$request->input('start_date'), $request->input('end_date')])
        ->groupBy('titulos.nome_titulo')
        ->groupBy('data_imports.data_import')
        ->orderBy('data_import')
        ->orderBy('titulos.nome_titulo')
        ->get();
```

Explicando brevemente o que é cada informação do eloquent:

**AtivosExtrato:** modelo onde fica as informações do rendimento diário;

**1) join:** tabela estrangeira para os nomes dos títulos

**2) join:** tabela estrangeira para o nome da corretora

**3) join:** tabela que salva a data da importação e relaciona com o id na tabela de ativosExtrato, ela tem função de reduzir o peso na hora das buscas e ganhar desempenho.

**where:** limitando ao usuário em questão

**WhereBetween:** limitando ao range de data

**1) groupBy:** Agrupando por títulos

**2) groupBy:** agrupando pela data de importação

Comment: No lugar da data não pode colocar month dela? exemplo `->groupBy(DB::raw('month(data_imports.data_import)'))` e na Select também só isso eu acho

Comment: Sim eu testei agora, ele ainda exibe todos, a lógica pensando bem [e que em vez de agrupar ele pegue o valor do ultimo dia do mês,

Comment: A sua dúvida está em dúvida, precisa colocar sempre o problema ...

Comment: não, necessariamente, eu só cogitei uma ideia, eu  só quero uma forma de pegar o valor agrupados por semana ou mês,